# FileOptions.Asynchronous causes FileStream.BeginRead to block

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, filestream, beginread

Why does creating a FileStream with FileOptions.Asynchronous cause FileStream.BeginRead to block the calling thread?

Here is the code snippet:

```
private static Task<int> ReadFileAsync(string filePath)
  {
     var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 64 * 1024, FileOptions.Asynchronous);
     FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
     byte[] buffer = new byte[fi.Length];
     Task<int> task = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(file.BeginRead, file.EndRead, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null);         
     return task.ContinueWith(t =>
     {
        file.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Done ReadFileAsync, read " + t.Result + " bytes.");
        return t.Result;
     });
  }
```

When digging around in the MSFT FileStream code using JetBrains dotPeek it seems like there is a bug in their code:

```
      if (!this._isAsync)
    return base.BeginRead(array, offset, numBytes, userCallback, stateObject);
  else
    return (IAsyncResult) this.BeginReadAsync(array, offset, numBytes, userCallback, stateObject);
```

The BeginRead method actually seems to do reading asynchronously by scheduling a Task, but the BeginReadAsync method actually ends up doing a synchronous read.
So their method naming nomenclature is backwards and the logic of which method is called is wrong. BeginRead should be called if this._isAsync == true.

So it seems that to get FileStream.BeginRead to return right away (asynchronously schedule a read) you actually have to set the useAsync parameter in the cosntructor to false.

Comment: What do you intend to show with the posted code snippet? I cannot derive any information from it.

Comment: the posted code above will reproduce the behavior where the executing thread blocks on line Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(...) until the read of the file is complete. So in essence it does the opposite of what I expect and reads the file synchronously instead of asynchronously. This behavior is what has me puzzled...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a knowledge base article that lists all the ways that can cause code you desire to be executed asynchronously to actually run synchronously.

[Asynchronous Disk I/O Appears as Synchronous on Windows NT, Windows 2000, and Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156932)

Does anything on the list apply to your situation?

Have you tried implementing the same behavior with .NET 4.5's [ReadAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread.aspx)?

I am quoting from MSDN:

> In the .NET Framework 4 and earlier versions, you have to use methods such as BeginRead and EndRead to implement asynchronous I/O operations. These methods are still available in the .NET Framework 4.5 to support legacy code; however, the new async methods, such as ReadAsync, WriteAsync, CopyToAsync, and FlushAsync, help you implement asynchronous I/O operations more easily.

*EDIT*  I am reproducing your issue with a 256MB file on OCZ Vertex 2 with ICH10 and Windows 7.  I am having to generate the file, reboot the PC to clear file cache, and then try and read the same file.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         string fileName = @"C:\Temp\a1.txt";
         int arraySize = 512 * 1024 * 1024;
         var bytes = new byte[arraySize];
         new Random().NextBytes(bytes);

          // This prints false, as expected for async call
         var callback = new AsyncCallback(result =>
                             Console.WriteLine("Completed Synchronously: " + result.CompletedSynchronously));

         try
         {
            // Use this method to generate file...
            //WriteFileWithRandomBytes(fileName, arraySize, bytes, callback);

            Console.WriteLine("ReadFileAsync invoked at " + DateTimeOffset.Now);
            var task = ReadFileAsync(fileName);
            Console.WriteLine("ReadFileAsync completed at " + DateTimeOffset.Now);

            Task.WaitAll(task);
            Console.WriteLine("Wait on a read task completed at " + DateTimeOffset.Now);
         }
         finally
         {
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
               File.Delete(fileName);
         }
      }

      private static void WriteFileWithRandomBytes(string fileName, int arraySize, byte[] bytes, AsyncCallback callback)
      {
         using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName,
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 128 * 1024, FileOptions.Asynchronous))
         {
            Console.WriteLine("BeginWrite invoked at " + DateTimeOffset.Now);
            var asyncResult = fileStream.BeginWrite(bytes, 0, arraySize, callback, null);


            Console.WriteLine("BeginWrite completed at " + DateTimeOffset.Now);
            // completes in 6 seconds or so...  Expecting instantaneous return instead of blocking

            // I expect runtime to block here...
            Task.WaitAll(Task.Factory.FromAsync(asyncResult, fileStream.EndWrite));

            // or at least when flushing the stream on the following end-curly
         }
      }


      private static Task<int> ReadFileAsync(string filePath)
      {
         FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[fi.Length];

         var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 64 * 1024, FileOptions.Asynchronous);
         Task<int> task = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(file.BeginRead, file.EndRead, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null);
         return task.ContinueWith(t =>
         {
            file.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Done ReadFileAsync, read " + t.Result + " bytes.");
            return t.Result;
         });
      }
   }
}
```

When all else fails, [here's the reference to unmanaged API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I am not sure, if this applies or not. It's hard to say.

Comment: Are you able to repro this behavior on your machine using the code snippet that I posted?

Comment: I've tried implementing this behavior with async/await and FileStream.ReadAsync method and I don't see this behavior. I see expected asynchronous read behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to pass in a valid stateObject, instead of null? Compare to code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys(v=vs.100).aspx